# How to iterate through a map with value as list?

Tags: scala

I am trying to iterate through the following map

```
scala> val m1 = Map("key1" -> List(1,2),  "key2" -> List(3,4))
```

I am not sure why the following code prints this way?

```
scala> m1 foreach {case (key, value) => println (key + "-->" + value .foreach {println} )}
1
2
key1-->()
3
4
key2-->()
```

I was hoping to get the following

```
key1 --> 1 2 
key2 --> 3 4
```

Comment: I would suggest going from `Map[A, B]` to `List[B]`, and then print.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't nest a `println` within another `println`. `println` expects a string as an argument, so if you want your list to be a space-separated string, use `mkString`:

```
scala> val m1 = Map("key1" -> List(1,2),  "key2" -> List(3,4))
m1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[Int]] = Map(key1 -> List(1, 2), key2 -> List(3, 4))

scala> m1 foreach {case (key, value) => println (key + "-->" + value.mkString(" ") )}
key1-->1 2
key2-->3 4

scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for comprehension, where you extract each key-list pair,

```
for ( (k,xs) <- m1 ) println(k + "->" + xs.mkString(" "))
```